# limiting listening ips on postgresql 9

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to restrict the listening IP's of a virtual machine to the local network only, I have tried `listening_addresses='192.168.*.*` and restarted and the connection is still being refused. Is there a way to restrict postgresql daemon to listening to a block of IP's?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PostgreSQL cannot listen at a block of IP addresses. You have to specify the IP addresses of all network interfaces on which it should listen. Usually this is one IP address per network card, plus localhost and perhaps some virtual IP addresses, not too hard to enumerate in `listen_addresses`.

But perhaps what you really want is to restrict access to the server to client within a certain IP range.
For that you have to add a line to `pg_hba.conf` that looks somewhat like this:

```
host  dbname  username  192.168.0.0/16  md5
```

You have to remove all more permissive lines (containing addresses like `0.0.0.0/0`).

Don't forget to reload with `pg_ctl reload`!